# connecting to sharepoint site from R

Tags: r, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I would like to connect to Sharepoint site from R. I have tried `Microsoft365R` package from the [AzureR](https://github.com/Azure/AzureR) family.
My question is which permission should I have on Azure side in order to authenticate and use this package ? By running :

`site <- sharepoint_site("https://myaadtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/my-site-name")`

I'm getting a browser popup for authentication. I am the owner of the sharepoint site I'm trying to access to, but still I need more previlage on Azure side which I don't know what are those ?!

Here is the error message I'm getting after putting my credentials :

`Need admin approval needs permission to access resources in  your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.`

[image]

Comment: @Sridevi, No ! That is exactly my question !! What are the pre-requirement that enable user to use the AzureR packages ? There is nothing about it on their github !

Comment: Are you running Microsoft365R inside a Shiny app on a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** like below:

[image]

I have created one test **Azure AD user** without assigning any directory roles like below:

[image]

When I tried to authorize the application with above **test user** credentials, I got **same error** as below:

[image]

The error usually occurs if the added *"API permissions"* are not consented by ***Global Administrator***.

If you want to get that privilege, contact admin and get yourself assigned with ***Global Administrator*** role like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Users -> Select user -> Assigned roles -> Add assignments***

[image]

After getting ***Global Admin*** role, sign in with that account and grant **admin consent** to *"API permissions"*  of your application like below:

[image]

You can also grant admin consent **on behalf of organization** using below URL:

```http
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/adminconsent?client_id=<appID>
```

[image]

When I signed in with **Global Admin** credentials, I got ***consent form*** like below:

[image]

After granting the **admin consent**, you will be able to authenticate successfully.

In your scenario, get yourself assigned with ***Global Admin privileges*** before running the code to connect SharePoint site from R that fixes the error.